# for loop # usage

Tags: shell, variable

I am trying to understand how this piece of code works:

```
for b in `git branch -r`; do git branch --track ${b##upstream/} $b; done
```

In particular, the part where it does

```
${b##upstream/}
```

I know it cuts the characters "upstream/" from $b, but I want to know how or why this works. I found this snippet on a forum.

Comment: I understand what the above code does, but I just don't know how it does it.

Comment: Sorry, could someone kindly let me know why my question was downvoted?

Answer (score -1):

The for loop is a little bit different from other programming languages. Basically, it let's you iterate over a series of 'words' within a string.

**For sample**

```
        #!/bin/bash
        for i in $( ls ); do
            echo item: $i
        done
```

On the second line, we declare i to be the variable that will take the different values contained in $( ls ).

The third line could be longer if needed, or there could be more lines before the done (4).

'done' (4) indicates that the code that used the value of $i has finished and $i can take a new value.

This script has very little sense, but a more useful way to use the for loop would be to use it to match only certain files on the previous example

This [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/bash-for-loop-examples/?utm_source=feedburner) will give you details explanation for you question. for is

Comment: Thank you. I understand how for loop works in Unix, but the part that I don't understand is how the characters "upstream/" are getting cut from $b in my example.

Comment: `man bash` - the section "Parameter Expansion" describes the `${var##word}` syntax (and other useful variants)